# P2P communication , chat App (android)

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, p2p

i am using [this](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2014/02/android-sercerclient-example-client.html) tutorial as guide. i am creating an android app which is basically chat application. this uses ***socket programming*** to communicate .

i want to connect directly to device and deliver the message. the message does not go to server. server only tell me the address of the device thats it.

i followed the tutorial i mentioned above and this only works for the case where client and server are within same wifi/network. i want to connect to server from client irrespective of their network connection place. how do i do it from any network to any network.

i think i need to use ***port forwarding*** , but this is not practical . so we better use a server for keeping track of all the ip changes. and deliver the messages directly from the source to client. so how do i do it. please suggest any resources.

**update**

as of now what i studied is i have to use ***innetaddress*** to communicate if i am inside an wifi router.

thank you

Comment: Port forwarding is a network configuration / administration problem, not a programming problem.  "How do i do it from any network to any network."  That is impossible.  It is only possible for networks that have been *configured* to do network forwarding; e.g. by configuring the router (on a home network).

Comment: so port forwarding is not practical right . so how can i achieve this .may be using server.  actually i am totally confused sir. can you suggest some docs to first get the concept right . my aim is that the message never goes through the server . it goes directly to the device. and i want to do it in a case where the devices are just connected to web (may be wifi or mobile data).

Comment: I think you are correct.  Port forwarding is not practical.  I think there is no general solution ... apart from relaying the chat messages via the server.  But you are unlikely to get a decent answer here ... because your question is off-topic.

Comment: so you are saying anyhow i have to pass all messages through a server ?

Comment: if it is off topic. which tags will give me the answer which might help me?

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) Off topic means that you are asking your question on the wrong place.  Ask it somewhere else; e.g. on the serverfault site.

Comment: ok . so lets get the direct to client messaging thing out of the way. then what  ... now i want to make all the messages through server . but the devices connected to it will be in different network. now how to solve this. any suggestion ...

Comment: Please follow my advice in the last comment.  This is my last comment on this question.